# Change all DIV elements to TABLE, TR, TD with its attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I have a code completely written with DIV based structure. There is a problem with this div based structure when it is rendered in EMAIL. The alignment is not the same in all EMAIL clients. So I was trying to convert all the DIV based structure to TABLE structure.

Here goes the actual code

```
<div class="layoutContainer" style="width: 880px; height: 700px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div class="contentInside" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); width: 260px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        test content1
    </div>
    <div class="contentInside" style="transform: translate(-375px, 0px); width: 394px; left: 399px; top: 0px;">
        test content2
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the above code to get converted as below

```
<table class="layoutContainer" style="width: 880px; height: 700px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <table class="contentInside" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); width: 260px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        test content1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="contentInside" style="transform: translate(-375px, 0px); width: 394px; left: 399px; top: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        test content2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can someone please help me in this.

Comment: Are you dynamically creating these divs? If not then just change divs structure to table structure. I don't know what help you need in that

Comment: yes it is dynamically created by a third party tool

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: @MohanKumarPR In that case you should write all the details first, like which 3rd party tool you are using. How it is rendering these divs and what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the div element behave like table using css.
**display:table**  -for table
**display:table-cell**  -for column
**display:table-row**  -for row

Comment: This is working fine in all browsers, but I am looking for something to render fine in all EMAIL clients. In OUTLOOK 2013, sometimes it is not working properly